# How to set same color to element when hovering it?

Tags: css, sass

I'm simply trying to set the **same** border color to element when showing up and when hovering it, but for some reason I can't get my sass to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Here's my sass:

**This doesn't work:**

```
.myfield{
  &:hover{
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
}
```

**This works:**

```
.myfield{
  border: 2px solid red;
  &:hover{
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
}
```

However I don't want to repeat the same border 2 times. What will be the right way to write this?

Comment: So you want the border to always there regardless if you’re hovering over it? How about just removing the &:hover from your second example?

Comment: `.myfield, .myfield:hover { }`

Comment: @AmauryHanser Nope it doesn't work because there's another class that is getting in the way, so I need to force the hover functionality

Comment: Then `border: inherit` in hover

Comment: I agree, since the hover changes **nothing** it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Paulie_D He did mention in comment before, that there is another style with border on hover, and he doesn't want that border, so he is trying to override it.
progx You should have mentioned that in your post.

Comment: Which is why we ask for DEMOS of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I may have a hard time seeing the use of setting same border twice (For selector and selector:hover), this may work for you:

```css
.myfield {
  &, &:hover{
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
}
```

as this produces:

```css
.myfield, .myfield:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

This should be the semantically equivalent of your code above (marked Working), that produces:

```css
.myfield {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.myfield:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**Edit:** Try taking a look at https://www.sassmeister.com/ for "simple" testing of what css is produced. It's often easier than trying it out "real life", especially when all sass/scss runs through an asset pipeline etc.